# JQuery Image Fade in Fade out without rel/abs positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an image gallery plugin that does basic fade in/fade out of images. The problem with all other plugins is that they use relative/absolute positioning.

Is it possible to have multiple images stacked on top of each other in a div that does not have absolute position on them?

My problem is the height of the container has to be set. I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: @if you don't make them abs positioned they will push other contents down?? is that ok

Comment: I dont want the contents of the faded out images to be pushed down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protip: if *everyone* else does it the same way, there's usually a reason.  You may want to read up on document flow (this document gives a pretty good explanation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow).  In order to get images to stack like that (and not push each other out of the way), they must be removed from the normal document flow (such as via absolute positioning).  This can also be accomplished with `float`, but that will present other problems.

You can achieve a similar effect with relative positioning, however, the relatively positioned element will still have its "normal" position reserved for it in the document flow, which could cause the rest of your document to get a bit screwy.

I think the short version of the answer is "no."  I'm open to someone proving me wrong though.

Comment: i agree with you , as long as it is the document flow , it will definetly pushes other items down.